# How to convert this into a 3D mesh plot?

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I have the following code :

```
a=7
f=10
T=1/f;
v=40
wl=v/f;
x1=1;
x2=30
step=0.01

t=x1:step:x2;
x=x1:step:x2;
y=a*sind(2*pi*f*(t+(x*T)/wl)); 
h=plot(x,y);
```

I tried `h=plot3(x,y,t)` but the line itself remains in 2D .. Should I convert this into a matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a grid of points and then use `mesh()`:

```
[x,t] = meshgrid(x,t);
y     = a*sind(2*pi*f*(t+(x*T)/wl)); 
mesh(y)
```

Comment: Thank you this works :) How can I assign different colors or pattern because it takes a while to render ?

Comment: The rendering depends on the number of gridpoints. You can change `colormap()` which will not affect speed of rendering.